# How to pass multiple collections in foreach loop in laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm trying to build a simple form based query system. It'll show all the queries and their responses to the user.
In controller, I'm returning questions model where user ID is `Auth::id()` .
Here's my schema:

```
| id | user_id | lesson_name | statement          | statement_type |
|--- | ------- | ----------- | ------------------ | -------------- |
| 1  | 1       | python      | Any question asked | question       |
| 2  | 1       | python      | Response by admin  | response       |
```

I want to show all the entries related to a user for a particular lesson. Here's what I've done till now:

**In the controller**

`$queries =  Question::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get()->groupBy('lesson_name');`

**In blade file**

```
    @foreach ($queries as $query)

        <div class="query-wrapper card">
            <a href="#" class="query-video-thumbnail"><img src="{{ asset('img/signup.jpg') }}" 
class="query-video-thumbnail"></a>
            <div class="vertical-wrapper query-wrapper-content" onclick="openQueryPopup()">
                    <h2 class="query-lesson-name">{{ $query->value('lesson_name') }}</h2>


                <p class="query-msg">Query message will show up here...</p>
                <p class="sender">Sangam replied</p>
            </div>
            <div class="vertical-wrapper">
                <a href="#" class="query-reply">Reply &nbsp;<i class="bi bi-send-fill"></i> 
   </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="query-container" class="query-container card">
            <h4>
                Your query about
                <br>
                Lesson name will appear here
            </h4>

            <div class="vertical-wrapper receiver-msg-div">
                @foreach ($query->pluck('statement_type') as $statementtype)
                    <p class="sender">{{ $statementtype }}:</p> 
                    <p class="query-msg">{{ $query->value('statement') }}</p>
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <div class="vertical-wrapper">
                <a href="#" class="query-reply">Reply &nbsp;<i class="bi bi-send-fill"></i> 
   </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="pseudo-container" onclick="closeQueryPopup()"></div>
     @endforeach
```

[UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IryDM.png)

[Here is database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOQ3J.png)

I'm not able to fetch `statement_type` and `statement` at the same time.
Any help is appreciated.

Edit 1

I simply want to loop all statements of `auth()->user()` with headings of `statement_type`

Comment: What is inside `$query`? Post one record.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I'm passing `queries` to the blade from my controller. I've mentioned it in the question.

Comment: I didn't ask what you're passing, asked **what sort of data inside the `foreach` loop**

Comment: @AbdullaNilam any response? I've attached the screenshot of my database

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I'm passing only strings.

Comment: Try to understand what I asked. Leave it. Someone here will help you. GL

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Hey brother, please help me I'm a newbie and I shared everything I had.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need a subquery inside your query to get current lesson's statement data (or messages, whatever it is)

I assumed your table name is questions

```
@foreach ($queries as $query)
  ..
  @php
    $subqueries = Question::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('lesson', $query->value('lesson_name'))->get();
  @endphp
  ..
  @foreach ($sub_queries as $sub_query)
    <p class="sender">{{ $sub_query->statement_type }}:</p>
    <p class="query-msg">{{ $sub_query->statement }}</p>
  @endforeach
  ..
```

If you need a correction just let me know

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by simply using `collect` Here's what I did with `$queries` variable:

```
$queries =  Question::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get()- >groupBy('lesson_name');
$questions = collect($queries)->groupBy('lesson_name');
$questions->values()->all();
```

### In Blade file

```
        @foreach ($question as $statementtype)
        <p class="sender">{{ $statementtype->statement_type }}:</p> 
        <p class="query-msg">{{ $statementtype->statement }}</p> 
        @endforeach
```